# How can I check if the users Password is the same as the user typed in the input of oldPassword?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, bcrypt

So, I basically wannt to check if the user's Password is the same as the password the user typed into the "oldPassword" input field. The problem I have is how I am suppose to check, cause apparently I have to hash, what the user typed into the input "oldPassword". How can I go about doing this, and please also check my ejs file and what you think? I got new password there as well, THIS IS FOR THE USER TO CHANGE IT'S OLD PASSWORD TO A NEW ONE BY THE WAY*

```
exports.postChangedPassword = async (req, res) => {
            const {
                oldPassword,
                newPassword,
                confirmNewPassword
            } = req.body;

            try {
                const userId = await req.params.userId;
                const user = await User.findById(userId)

                const oldHashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(oldPassword, 10);

                if (user.password === oldHashedPassword && newPassword === confirmNewPassword) {
                    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10);
                    user.password = hashedPassword;
                    user.save();
                    console.log(user);
                    res.render("admin/settings/appliedSettings/changed-password", {
                        pageTitle: "Succesfully Changed Password",
                        path: "/settings/changed-password",
                        user: user
                    })
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                req.flash("error", "Password do not match!");
                res.redirect("/settings/password");

            }
        }
```

model.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");




const postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    context: String,
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }
});


const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    posts: [postSchema]
});


userSchema.pre("save", async function save(next) {
    const user = this;
    if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    user.password = hashedPassword;
    next();
});


const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = {
    User,
    Post
}
```

change-password.ejs

```html
    <% if (errorMessage) { %>
        <div class="user-message-error"> <%= errorMessage %> </div>
        <% } %>
    <form class="change-password" action="/settings/changed-password/<%=user._id%>" method="POST">
        <label for="password">Old Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="oldPassword" placeholder="Enter Your Old Password ..." required>
        <label for="password">Your New Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="newPassword" placeholder="Enter Your New Password ..." required>
        <label for="password">Confirm Your New Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirmNewPassword" placeholder="Confirm Your Password ..." required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
        <button type="submit">
            Submit Password
        </button>
    </form>
```

admin route

```js
router.post("/settings/changed-password/:userId", adminController.postChangedPassword);
```

Comment: Seems okay. Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the password changed, just hash the new password and compare the hashed value to the old one:

```
const oldHashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(oldPassword, 10);
const newHashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10);
if (
    user.password === oldHashedPassword &&
    newPassword === confirmNewPassword &&
    oldHashedPassword !== newHashedPassword
) {
  user.password = newHashedPassword;
  user.save();
  console.log(user);
  res.render("admin/settings/appliedSettings/changed-password", {
    pageTitle: "Succesfully Changed Password",
    path: "/settings/changed-password",
    user: user
  })
}
```

It doesn't matter whether you check against `user.password` or `oldHashedPassword`, since you established that they are the same thing in the first condition

Comment: Still this loads forever aswell? Maybe I should declare the consts outside the try block or nah ?

Comment: You didn't say anything about loading forever. Is this first function executed in the front-end or in the back-end?

Comment: what is that for a question, it is a normal function and idk why it loads forever i tried tons of different stuffs im about to kill myself

Comment: plus im just doing back end, im not forking it with react or anyth

Comment: You're using a JavaScript framework I'm not familiar with as a back-end. I'll ask all questions I feel I need to, otherwise I won't be able to help you. Is it possible to debug your code using something like VS code or another IDE? Otherwise, add logging statements in between to check which line is the one that hangs

Comment: yeah aight, thanks doe for ur time btw, a mate told me to use the debugger just watched a 20 min tutorial gonna use the debugger soon i need an icecream first